# how to insert an html link into an array string?

Tags: javascript

a bit confused here. I have an array that's full of answers to questions and am having trouble getting the link to appear as.. an actual link. I've tried document.write but it's just breaking my page. Any ideas?

```
this.answer = [
    'answer1' + '<a href="URL">click here</a>',
    'answer 2', 
    'answer 3'
]
```

I have no idea how to write the `<a href="URL">click here</a>` bit to get it to not appear as just a string of text instead of HTML. Any ideas? My array is in a Shadow DOM custom HTML5 element, also. I know how to target the shadow DOM, just not sure of the basic format..

Thanks!
- Shan

**edit:** Thanks for the response, mplungjan. Like this?

```
this.answer = [
    'answer1' + innerHTML('<a href="URL">click here</a>'),
    'answer 2', 
    'answer 3'
]
```

this makes the entire thing appear blank on my page, however.. Think I'm formatting it wrong

**edit 2** okay trying to fix it based on the answers I got.. I tried this:

```
 var insertThis = document.getElementById('myElement').innerHTML = '<a href="#">Click here</a>';

 this.answer = [
    'answer1' + insertThis,
    'answer 2', 
    'answer 3'
]
```

but it's still making my array totally blank :( sorry I am pretty new to arrays it is very confusing to me.. Do i need to put the entirety of my first array item in the innerHTML including the 'answer1' bit?

**edit** it says that I cannot set innerHTML of null.. but when I console log my element right before I get the element by id it logs it fine.. hmm

Comment: You need to use innerHTML - show where you want to have the link appear

Comment: You need to put the string into the `innerHTML` of some DOM element. That's when it gets parsed as HTML, and turned into a link.

Comment: `innerHTML()` isn't a function, aren't you getting an error when you try to call it? You have the JS console open when you're testing Javascript, don't you?

Comment: You have to use something like `document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = this.answer[0];`

Comment: I added to my question, thank you for your responses

Comment: Ok nvm, I was getting the element wrong due to it being in the shadowDOM -- If you want to answer it with your solution to set it to this.answer[0] I will accept it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the comments to your post, the text isn't being processed as HTML when you're putting it in the DOM of your page.

You need to set the `innerHTML` of your element to be a value of the array, like this:

```
    var answer = [
        'answer1' + '<a href="URL">click here</a>',
        'answer 2', 
        'answer 3'
    ];

    document.getElementById("yourelement").innerHTML = answer[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var aColor = [
    '<a href="#red">red</a>',
    '<a href="#green">green</a>',
    '<a href="#blue">blue</a>'
];

var x = Math.floor(Math.random() % 3);

document.getElementById('elementId').innerHTML = aColor[x];
```

The array has three elements in it. Each element contains a string. Each string contains a representation of a link for an assorted color. The variable 'x' is a random address for the array, (0, 1, 2).